# typescript named parameters like used in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to learn both TypeScript and Angular (and thus JavaScript).

Going through the Angular tutorials, I see they do stuff like this:

In normal javascript:

```js
function CreateCtrl($scope, $location, Project){
// do stuff
}
```

For full example, see the "Wire up a backend" project.js example
on the [Angular homepage](https://angularjs.org).

The kicker is, those parameters could be in any order (or not there at all), and `Project` is actually a user defined variable/type.    The Angular framework is able to map the parameters to actual objects.

So now to Typescript,  how can I recreate this type of functionality?   I would like to describe Angular's behavior in some way, to let me wrap it in Typescript (strongly type this flexible property injection).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is an [AngularJS type definition on Definitely Typed](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/angularjs) that lets you use Angular from TypeScript.

If I was creating a definition for an existing function such as this (in the absence of named arguments), I would probably either define them in a specific order (even though I know they *could* be passed in varying orders in plain JavaScript) or create a set of function overloads that matched the possibilities I wanted to expose, like this:

```
interface Example {
    ($scope: bool, $location: string, Project: number): void;
    ($location: string, $scope: bool, Project: number): void;
    (Project: number, $scope: bool, $location: string): void;
}

declare var example: Example;
```

When I attempt to call `example(` I get intellisense with the three options and if I don't use one of these combinations I get a compiler warning.

In JavaScript, named arguments are normally created with an object, so if I was writing a new method that could accept arguments in this way I would do this...

```
interface ExampleArguments {
    scope: bool;
    location: string;
    project: number;
}

var example = function (exampleArguments: ExampleArguments) {

};

example({ scope: true, project: 4, location: 'hi' });
```

Which is statically typed and checked in TypeScript.

Comment: basically it sounds like you are saying "no, you can't do it".  is that right?

i use angularjs d.ts and that doesn't help.

also, your bottom example, angular's framework does the calling, so i don't have any control over that.      maybe typescript doesn't have any way of handling this right now huh.

Comment: Named arguments were proposed, but rejected from the TypeScript language specification - so it isn't possible to allow exactly as you describe - but you can formalise it so they are in a fixed order and get what you want (even though Angular would accept any order). http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/256