# How can I indirectly specify an argument name in a function type?

Tags: typescript

I want to pull the name of my function type's argument out of another type.  Maybe like this, for instance:

```
type F_v1 = (name: number) => boolean;
type A = ["name", number];
//type F_v2 = (A[0]: A[1]) => boolean; // this is not really allowed
```

Is there any way to do this?

(I'm assuming that the argument names are actually part of their function types - TypeScript IDEs seem to know how to read argument names from an arbitrary function type, anyway.  And even something like `(...as: A) => boolean` ends up with argument names such as "as_0".)

Comment: The name of the argument is not really part of the signature

Comment: Does this answer your question? [typescript named parameters like used in angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14931824/typescript-named-parameters-like-used-in-angularjs)

Comment: No.  Juan's comment is certainly relevant though, if it's correct.  Even in that case I'd still like to tell the IDE what the names are somehow, but I guess that wouldn't be feasible without IDE-specific language extensions (and I wouldn't be interested in those).

Answer (score 1):

You can kind of do this with labeled tuples ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#labeled-tuple-elements)) and array spread syntax:

```
type F_v1 = (name: number) => boolean;

type A = [name: number];
type F_v2 = (...args: A) => boolean;
```

and you could even use the `Parameters` ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype)) utility type to extract the parameter type from a function:

```
type F_v3 = (...args: Parameters<F_v1>) => boolean;
```

Functions of type `F_v2` and `F_v3` show with the same named parameters as `F_v1`:

```
const test= (f1: F_v1, f2: F_v1, f3: F_v3) => {
  type T1 = typeof f1 // (name: number) => boolean
  type T2 = typeof f2 // (name: number) => boolean
  type T3 = typeof f3 // (name: number) => boolean
}
```

For `f3` there is a difference in type errors though, as these will refer to `args` rather than `name`.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg+gNwIxQLxQBQDsCGBbCALiiwFc8AjCAJwEo0A+KCgexYBsIcsBuAKD6hIUAIJooAbVwFiZSjQC6-IdHgIATOIwA6XTmoBzAM7ER9VE1YcuvAStiIAzFt3b9x4gAV9+CMBpGADxqSAzmlmyc3Px8AMYsWEbAUP5J6BgAZkjEIQA0UBnqOYhI+RmOxQiO4VAA3nxQKeDQACoo6CosGQUoAPS9mNJEJORUdIzMkTYNTcItmh3NXQWa-YO+sqM0NVZRWDP2Lc6LkMvlUGvYGyPy4xaT1tx8AL58QA)

Comment: Ah cool I didn't know about labeled tuples.  That's good to learn!  I don't think it quite helps in my situation; I still want a way to turn a label into a literal type or a literal type into a label, I think, and I imagine that's not allowed.  (It's not really a big deal though; I can handle having weird auto-generated argument names here and there.)

Comment: Yeah, as far as I know there is no way to extract the label strings from the types. I just called them `x1`, `x2`, etc. in some code where I wanted to pretty-print a function type.